# HM-10 only works with Iphone apps

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, hm-10

My HM-10 BLE connects to Samsungs and Iphones. But when I want to see the real distance from the phone to the Beacon, then only Iphone apps (e.g Locate Beacon) show the actual distance. Samsung apps always show 0.08 or 0.09 meters to the Beacon. Any help? Thanks.
Picture from Locate Beacon app:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Wlh.png)

Comment: If you use the Locate Beacon app for Android on the Samsung device, what does it say the distance is?  What does it say the RSSI is?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response David. I added the screenshot from app the question above. But the RSSI is always -47 or -48 and distance 0.09m or 0.08m, regardless of the actual distance.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem with your Samsung phone. The RSSI should become increasingly negative as you get further away. It should not say -47 or -49 at 5 meters away or more... There is no way the signal is that strong at such a distance. Once you get to 20 or more meters away the RSSI should drop closer to -90 and then reach about -100 before no longer detecting the beacon. If it does not do this, then the phone has a faulty RSSI sensor of firmware that decodes its value.